# Lag when using Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

After the latest Ubuntu update (using 19.04) I get an extraordinary lag when using my Logitech M720 mouse connected via Bluetooth.

When using the USB dongle it works flawless.

Any ideas on why this might have occurred? (tried removing it, pairing it again and so forth)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same mouse on Kubuntu 18.04. I observed that sometimes (probably a specific uptime/boot, not physical location), it worked via BT at home and needed dongle at work and sometimes the opposite.

Answer (score 7):

After trying to downgrade the bluetooth package to see if that made a difference, I decided/realized that while it may have improved somewhat, it did not fix the issue. Continued researching and found: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2372916.

Suggestion is:

`echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf`

Then restart.

Seems to be working substantially better

Comment: Do you happen to know what "bluetooth coexistence parameter" means. Or what could be possible side effects of this solution?

Comment: [Here](https://www.ecnmag.com/article/2012/03/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-coexistence) is a more technical explanation (which might be based on [this](https://home.zhaw.ch/~kunr/NTM1/literatur/laird-wireless-bluetooth-wifi-coexistence.pdf) whitepaper) and a more accessible explanation can be found [here](http://tomatousb.org/settings:wireless#toc8).

TL;DR: older (2.4Ghz) wifi can sometimes interfere with BT. Those speed/connectivity issues can be mitigated with BT co-existence thing, if both BT devices support it.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( (Btw I noticed that file didn't exist before running the command).

Answer (score 7):

The issue you are facing is not related to the Bluetooth timeout but more likely the USB auto suspend feature built into the kernel.

I am running **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** and i have a **Logitech MX Anywhere 2S**

This is how i went about fixing it:

1. Run command to find out the id of your bluetooth module

```bash
$ lsusb -vt

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. 
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:565a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:565a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
```

The id of my bluetooth module is **8087:0aaa**

2. Create or update a udev rule to disable auto suspend for the module.

```bash
$ echo 'ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", ATTR{idProduct}=="0aaa", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="-1"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules
```

After this reboot your pc and the lag should go away.

Note that **idVendor** was set to **8087** and **idProduct** was set to **0aaa** to reflect my bluetooth settings

I used following links for reference.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#USB_autosuspend

Comment: Seems to have worked for me on pop-os 22.04 using the latest 6.0.12.x kernel.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 22.10 with the latest 6.2.8 kernel

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot!  This solved the issue on a brand new Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Nothing has work for me until now. It makes total sense this feature, but legacy HW does not support it. ThinkPad P14s Gen 3 Debian 12 - 6.1.0-17. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Logitech MX Ergo on Pop OS 19.10 (running on a ThinkPad E15) and

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf
```

solved it for me. It improved both issues that I was experiencing:

- an occasional lag of around 0.5 seconds where the pointer completely stopped moving,
- the mouse pointer generally became much more fluid, there were many micro-stutters before.

Thanks to BHuber!

Answer (score 0):

The above workaround worked for me for a while, but, few days ago, my mouse started to lag again.

I found this [tutorial](https://winaero.com/fix-bluetooth-mouse-lag-on-linux-for-device-without-transmitter/), that seems to work.

In resume:

1. Find the address of your mouse:

```
bluetoothctl devices | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read uuid; do bluetoothctl info $uuid; done|grep -e "Device\|Connected\|Name"
```

[image]
2. Edit file:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/<you mouse address>/info
```

3. Change the **MinInterval** and **MaxInterval**. I changed to 5, you may want to play with numbers here.
4. Restart Bluetooth adapte:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

I hope it helps.